# Can we get value of ValueProvider<String> object in STRING format in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am using Template to run my job in dataflow, I pass filepath as argument to code through template, in dataflow code I want to get that filepath in STRING format.
I used options.getInputFile().toString it's printing object not a actual filepath.

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ValueProvider#get`, as described in [Using ValueProvider in your functions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-functions).